# Via python get a list of all functions available, local, global or imported?

Tags: python-3.x

Via python get a list of all functions available, local, global or imported?  Using globals() and locals() is incomplete.  I suspect the inspect module might be part of such effort?

Comment: so you want a list of all possible local, global *and* imported functions?

Comment: Yes, a list of all functions (i.e., methods) a given script can call at the time the list is generated. The available examples seem to assume that you just want to query a given module, not an exhaustive list.  I suspect using inspect module or such, you would have to build a list of all available modules (to a given script) then query each module for available methods.  But then how would one add to the exhaustive list the functions in the script its self, not from an imported module?